# How to write regex in jmeter to extract string value from url

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am working with Jmeter.
I have to parse URL and extract below bold text from the URL.
Can anyone help me how to write Regular expression for below?
Finally I want to extract below bold text and want to use that text in next request.

`https://c.na14.content.force.com/secur/contentDoor?startURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp&sid=00Dd0000000eKuN%21AREAQGZHTwz3BeGCrY4kx8o1uD26J9APW91RbyzaKd2LX5j42g_r59LEFp1RptxRzmRTAA1RDCvK.mqefotkhxU6T9n53sIQ&skipRedirect=1&lm=.hmCC3PYB2DNtzRUeuP4dA%3D%3D`

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to extract your sid values
sample regexp : `sid=(.+)&skipRedirect`

Answer (score 0):

The regex below should extract the part you are looking for:

```
\?.*sid=([^&]*)
```

Unless there are some fringe scenarios I am not thinking of.